# Open multiple links in Chrome at once as new tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, tabs, popup

I'm trying to open multiple links at once in Google Chrome in new tabs but it fails.

Problems:

1. Blocked by popup
2. Open in new windows instead of tab after the user allowed the popup

---

With [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVaEFssH4o4qDycSUNGD?p=preview), I can open multiple links at once in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" >');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="openLinks()">Open</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, I came across someone who found [a workaround](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=en).

I tried using `setInterval` to try to open the links individually but it didn't work.

Comment: This seems a little iffy, you're trying to bypass popup blocks even though they were made for this specific reason, to block popups... :L

Comment: I'm not doing some fishy stuff.. look at the extension, how the developer bypassed it? hmm

Comment: Do you want to do that [independently of browser settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)? I don't think that that's possible.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do this in vanilla JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
    window.open("http://www.java2s.com/")
    window.open("http://www.java2s.com/")
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a more Chrome-specific implementation (if popup blockers are giving you difficulty):

```
var linkArray = []; // your links
for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
    // will open each link in the current window
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: linkArray[i]
    });
}
```

Here is some documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

Comment: "vanilla JavaScript" works nicely in your example. but a page with multiple open_win functions (and corresponding buttons) does not open multiple tabs for each button:

Comment: the "vanilla JavaScript" is no longer working in chrome (January 2018), it's opening a single tab, not two..

Comment: As of July 2018 I believe the best solution is something like this:   

`window.open("https://www.ecosia.org", "_new");
window.open("https://www.duckduckgo.com", "secondWindow");`   


The trick is to make sure that the second window has a name other than `_new` otherwise the browser will try to stick the link into the same window overriding the first `window.open`.  

I have tried this in Chrome and IE and it works for me.

Comment: As of Nov 2019, tfantina's code only opens one tab on mobile Safari (iOS 13.2). Works fine on Mac Safari (13.0.3) though.

Comment: dude, your second solution was awesome.

Answer (score 7):

The reason that the browser extension can do it is because Chrome extensions [have access to a special Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows), which lets you use:

```
chrome.windows.create({tabid: n})
```

where `createData` has a `tabid` value greater than any current tab (and you can find the greatest current `tabid` using `chrome.windows.getAll()`).

However, in terms of doing it on your page (or anywhere that's not a Chrome extension), that's not possible, since [whether or not a new window opens in a new tab is determined entirely by the user's settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript).

Comment: This is correct. Browser extensions can do a lot more than a webpage can. Despite both using javascript, they are very, very different things.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to open multiple tabs or windows is by using `setTimeout()` of 500ms.

```
window.open("https://facebook.com", "one", windowFeatures);
setTimeout(function(){
  window.open("https://facebook.com", "two", windowFeatures);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning that you need to *actually* have popups allowed in your browser settings. Don't rely on browser alert asking you if you want to allow the popup to open.

[image]

Comment: Save the day, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The following code will open multiple popUp on the button click.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function open_win() {
 window.open("url","windowName","windowFeatures")
 window.open("url","DifferentWindowName","windowFeatures")// different name for each popup
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
</body>
```

you need to make sure that each window name is different, otherwise the last popup will overwrite it's previous popup. As a result you will end up with a single popup.

Answer (score 1):

User will have to allow popups but I ended up doing this:

```
function openMultipleTabs(urlsArray){

    urlsArray.forEach(function(url){
        let link     = document.createElement('a');
        link.href    = url;
        link.target  = '_blank';
        link.click();
    });

}
```

Comment: This only opens it in one tab for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution playing with setTimeout, check below

```
function openMultipleTabs(urlsArray: string[]) {
  urlsArray.forEach((url: string, key: number) => {
    if (key === 0) {
      window.open(url, `_blank_first_${key.toString()}`);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("resolved", key);
        window.open(url, `_blank_${key.toString()}`);
      }, 1500 * key);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like extension uses below code to open those tabs.

```
function openTab(urls, delay, window_id, tab_position, close_time) {
    var obj = {
            windowId: window_id,
            url: urls.shift().url,
            selected: false
    }

    if(tab_position != null) {
        obj.index = tab_position
        tab_position++;
    }

    chrome.tabs.create(obj, function(tab) {
        if(close_time > 0) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
            }, close_time*1000);
        }
    });

    if(urls.length > 0) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {openTab(urls, delay, window_id, tab_position, close_time)}, delay*1000);
    }

}
```

If you want to take a look at the code of the extension for reference you will find the extensions in (for Windows) `C:\Documents and Settings\*UserName*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`

Comment: While it may be interesting to look at the code of a browser extension, this code WILL NOT WORK on a website.

Comment: `chrome.tabs.create` is part of the Chrome API that I discussed in my answer -- it's not going to work on a webpage.

Comment: I know it won't work in a webpage since it uses chrome api. That was for answering his question about how extension developer achieved it.

Answer (score -1):

Since modern browsers (and even old ones with blockers), will absolutely not allow this (one user action, one new tab). My solution was:

```
    openInfoLinks = () => {
        const urlsArray = [
            `https://...`,
            `https://...`,
            `https://...`,
        ]
        window.open(
            urlsArray[this.linkCounter],
            `_blank_${someIdentifier}_${this.linkCounter}`
        );
        this.linkCounter++;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.linkCounter = 0;
        }, 500);
    }
```

The user can open the links in quick succession with ctrl+click-ing the button N times.

Comment: Could you give a test reference where such a solution works ? Tnx in advance

Comment: sure, https://codesandbox.io/s/young-architecture-7nzot?file=/src/App.js