# How to use multiple links in one element in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys is there any way to add more than one link to the same thing?

What I want to do is to when some one clicks on a link they will be opening like two to three pages at the same time.

Lets say I have this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a>History</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How I could make the link open more than one page?

Comment: That sounds like a really spammy idea.  why would you want to do this?  People expect 1 link to open 1 destination.  If you do more than that, it's likely not going to go over well with users.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using JavaScript.
See previous posts:

- [How to make a link open multiple pages when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065030/1147709)
- [Open multiple links in Chrome at once as new tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24435877/1147709)

But since most browsers block popups like this, it's not a good idea to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

this might help,

```
    <a href="#" class="yourlink">Click Here</a>
```

In JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
window.open('http://yoururl1.com');
window.open('http://yoururl2.com');
});
```

Window.open is sometimes blocked by popup blockers and/or ad-filters.
To learn more, visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Answer (score 0):

No that cannot be done strictly with HTML. However, you can use javascript or jquery to do this. Here is an example.

Your HTML `a` tag needs to fire a javascript function:

```
<a onclick="runredirect()">Click me!</a>
```

Then add a script tag at the end of your body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var runredirect = function() {
        var redirectWindow1 = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
        redirectWindow1.location;
        var redirectWindow2 = window.open('http://yahoo.com', '_blank');
        redirectWindow2.location;
        var redirectWindow3 = window.open('http://bing.com', '_blank');
        redirectWindow3.location;
    }
</script>
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=”#link1″ onclick=”window.open(‘#link2′); window.open(‘#link3′)”>Page link </a>
```

By using above code you can add any number of pages, as I added three.

Comment: no pls dont do this

Answer (score 0):

You can't with HTML alone, there's only a single `href` attribute.

You can do it with Javascript. Something along these lines:

```
<script>
function openLinks(links) {
  for (let link of links) window.open(link, '_blank');
}
</script>
<a onclick="openLinks(['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.amazon.com'])">History</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the window.open() method in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function(){
     window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
     window.open('https://www.bing.com', '_blank');

})
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).