# Window.open opens a blank empty new tab for no reasons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I have a very simple link that tries to open 2 new tabs:

```js
function multipleTabs() {
  window.open("http://firstlink/","_blank"); 
  window.open("http://secondlink/","_blank");
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="multipleTabs();">Open 2 tabs</a>
```

The issue is that when I click the link, the 2 tabs are opened fine but it appears another blank new tab, for a total of 3 new tabs.

How can I prevent the third blank tab to be opened?
**Note: you have to allow the pop up in your chrome page to make this working**

PS. the solution can be also just chrome specific as I don't use other browser for this page.

Comment: could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364117/open-multiple-links-in-chrome-at-once-as-new-tabs

Comment: [I only get one tab](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ju875mhp/), not two, not three -- which doesn't surprise me, as opening multiple tabs in response to a single click used to be commonly abused by nefarious websites, so browsers disallow it. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP seems to get three tabs not one?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Right. My point above is that I can't replicate that behavior with the code provided.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: you have to allow pop-up in your chrome for the specific page

Comment: @giò - When I do that, I only two the two desired tabs, not three.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="javascript:multipleTabs()">Open 2 tabs</a>
```

I usually avoid using javascript:void(0) as long as I can for avoiding this type of issues, however for some reason both works-for-me.