# Use window.open to open two tabs at the same time

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering is it possible to open two tabs at the click of one button using window.open().
I have the following function:

```
$(".saleForm").on("click", ".btnPrintOrderBill", function(){

    var saleCode = $(this).attr("saleCode");

    window.open("extensions/tcpdf/pdf/food_order.php?code="+saleCode, "_blank");
    window.open("extensions/tcpdf/pdf/drink_order.php?code="+saleCode, "_blank");

})
```

and the following button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btnPrintOrderBill" saleCode="<?php echo $value["code"]; ?>" value="hold" name="openTable">Hold</button>
```

At the moment it just opens the first link but does nothing for the second link.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364117/open-multiple-links-in-chrome-at-once-as-new-tabs

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding http://localhost/ to the list of allowed pop-ups on chrome. I should have done it earlier !!!!