# How can i make my Href image load 2 separate URLs

Tags: html, href

Hi I am using a href code to make a image button. Can anyone tell me how to add a secondary action to the button mainly 2 url triggers on click.

My example is fairly easy

```
<a> href="example.com"><img src="source-image.png" /></a>
```

So the current page goes to the new URL in its current window, but a new window opens with another Url for payment method.

Can it be done??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open multiple links in Chrome at once as new tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364117/open-multiple-links-in-chrome-at-once-as-new-tabs)

Comment: Try [window.open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) to open new window with the new url when the link clicked and keep your link href like who is

Answer (score 0):

- use `window.open()` or shortly `open()` method which will popup new window with presented uri
- also becareful because in your html you closed `a` tag before adding `href` attribute

> Html

```
<a href="example.com" id="elem">
  <img src="source-image.png" />
</a>
```

> JS

```
var elem = document.getElementbyId("elem");
elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.open("https://developer.mozilla.org");
});
```